# How to query nested items in GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, graphql, menu, strapi

I'm using Strapi CMS and I would like to get all data for my menu. There's a REST request
example to do that

`await fetch( '/api/menus/3?nested&populate=*' );`

Response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": 3,
    "attributes": {
      "title": "Main Menu",
      "items": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": 10,
            "attributes": {
              "title": "Parent Page",
              "url": "/parent-page",
              "target": null,
              "children": [
                {
                  "id": 11,
                  "attributes": {
                    "title": "Child Page",
                    "url": "/child-page",
                    "target": null,
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "id": 12,
                        "attributes": {
                          "title": "Grandchild Page",
                          "url": "/grandchild-page",
                          "target": null,
                          "children": []
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
}
```

I would like to query the same data using GraphQL but no clue how to do that.

I tried passing filters, pagination, etc. to items, but I didn't find anything about the ability to specify 'nested'

```
query GetMenu {
  menusMenu(id: 1){
    data {
      id
      attributes {
        title
        slug
        items {
          data {
            attributes {
              title
              url
              target
              element_type
              is_disabled

              // throw an error Cannot query field "children" on type "MenusMenuItem".
              children {
                id
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

At the output I want to have a response with a repeating structure as in the REST example